# Convert Multiple Spaces to &nbsp; At Beginning of Line with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, indentation, line-breaks

I'm working on a text input for the backend of a website. I want a couple things to be automatically corrected. Example, new lines in the textarea I convert to `<br>`. I also want to let the user tab over on new lines.

This requires changing spaces over to `&nbsp;`. I only want to convert spaces that are at the start of a new line though.  Example, say the user types this into a textarea:

```
This is my text! It's pretty great.
This is a second line.
    This is a third line, that is indented by four spaces.
This is a fourth line.
```

Using regex, I've gotten the first space on each line to convert:

```
.replace(/^[ ]/mg,'&nbsp;');
```

I've gotten multiple spaces to convert to one space:

```
.replace(/[ ]{2,}/mg,'&nbsp;');
```

I can't figure out how to convert all four of those indenting spaces though. I've been scouring the internet for about 3 hours, and I've found similar answers, but nothing that I could get to work here. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function escapeSpaces(str) {
    var regex = /^ +/mg;

    return str.replace(regex, function (match) {
        var result = "";
        for (var i = 0, len = match.length; i < len; i++) {
            result += "&nbsp;";
        }
        return result;
    });
}
```

This may not be the best solution, but it works.

Alternatively:

```
function escapeSpaces (str) {
    return str.replace(/^ +/mg, function (match) {
        return match.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");
    });
}
```

Comment: Both of those worked until I replaced linebreaks '\n' with <br>. This broke them.

Comment: The capturing parentheses are unnecessary and slightly inefficient.  Use `match` instead of `spaces` to get rid of them and the `spaces` parameter. Also, you do not need to replace if there is *no* space, so use `+` instead of `*`.

Comment: @AndyM “Doctor, my arm hurts if I move it.” Don't do it, then. Do it *later*.

Comment: @POintedEars I'm not entirely sure what you are saying here, in regards to your second comment. I got everything working, as detailed above.

Comment: @AndyM What you have accepted is overly complicated and error-prone. If you just had switched the replacement order …  Is it not obvious that this *correct* answer *cannot* work *if* you replaced `"\n"` with `"<br>"` *before*?

Comment: I don't see why replacing a \n with a <br> would cause Bart's answer to break. I realize it does, but I don't see why. He doesn't call \r or \n in his script anywhere, he calls for spaces.

Comment: Using his method and flipping to replace the lines after, I got it working. You say this is less error prone, can you explain why?  http://jsfiddle.net/djTyP/5/

Comment: @AndyM Consider the regular expression `/^ +/mg;`. The `^` token matches the start of the input. If the "m" flag is used, the `^` token will match the start of each line for multiline input. Thus, replacing `\n` with `<br>` *before* running the regular expression will break the code, since your linebreaks (`\n`) have been replaced and ^ will no longer be able to match newlines.

Comment: Ohh, good point. That does make sense. I would think theoretically there'd be a way to map based on there `<br>`'s end, but there's no point because it works perfectly by putting the line breaks in afterwards. Well I very much appreciate the help, from both of you!