# Span duplicating input text messes up other consecutive whitespaces

Tags: javascript, css

I am back again with my *apparently* ambitious project.

So, I am trying to duplicate my input text into a span and hide the original text.

```
  $('#street_1').on("input" ,function() {
              document.getElementById('street1span').innerHTML = document.getElementById('street_1').value.substring(0, 10) + '<span style="color: red;">' + document.getElementById('street_1').value.substring(10) + '</span>';
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v127c14p/9/)

The problem I am having now, is that if you place more than one whitespace consecutively, they are not registered by the span:
 [image]
(one whitespace works just fine)

I am looking for a way to, perhaps, register white spaces as characters.

Comment: How is this question related to angular? I can't see any angular in your fiddle

Comment: Sorry, you are right, in the fiddle I used JQ, but on my website I use only angular

Comment: What is that you actually want to solve?

Comment: @Vivz sorry, I switched up prototype js with angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. `.value.substring(0, 10).replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;')` is what you need. It converts multiple white spaces to `&nbsp;` which is html for white space.

```
$('#street_1').on('input' ,function() {
    document.getElementById('street1span').innerHTML = document.getElementById('street_1').value.substring(0, 10).replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;') + '<span style="color: red;">' + document.getElementById('street_1').value.substring(10).replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;') + '</span>';

   });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v127c14p/21/)

Comment: My bad. Try now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace all repeated white spaces with only one space `str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')`

Also notice that your code example have been refactored to only use jQuery.

Code:

```js
$('#street_1').on('input' ,function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      html = '';
  
  $this.val($this.val().replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
  
  html = $this.val().substring(0, 10) + 
    '<span style="color: red;">' + 
      $this.val().substring(10) + 
    '</span>';
    
  $('#street1span').html(html); 
});
```

```css
#div {position: relative;}#street_1 {font-family: "Times New Roman";caret-color: black; z-index: 1;font-size: 1em;}#street1span {display: inline-block;font-size: 1em;font-family: "Times New Roman";white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;width: 98%;position: absolute;top: 2px;left: 1px;padding: 1px;z-index: 2;pointer-events: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
  <input id="street_1"/>
  <span id="street1span"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an alternative solution I hadn't thought about. Is it possible to do this without using JQuery, with just prototype?

Comment: Sure, you can do it by using the code `str.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')` where `str` is the variable that holds the input value..

Comment: Thank you, but I have to give the correct answer to @abhig10, since his solution is more of what I was asking.

Comment: @JurģisTomsLiepiņš Great you have found a good solution to your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is because multiple spaces are not recognized unless specified as nbsp;. You need a function to do that.

```
function escapeSpaces (str) {
    return str.replace(/^ +/mg, function (match) {
        return match.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");
    });
}
```

Use like this escapeSpaces(document.getElementById('street_1').value.substring(0, 10)) while concatenating strings.

ref -
 [Convert Multiple Spaces to &nbsp; At Beginning of Line with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815256/convert-multiple-spaces-to-nbsp-at-beginning-of-line-with-javascript)

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle for this? I can't really wrap my head around how to use this in y case